# How can I transform numbers in a range of 0-1 to a 1-52 range using Discrete Uniform Distribution in Python?

Tags: python, montecarlo

What I am looking for is for a method in Python or any other way to solve this, for what I know there is one method, but I couldn't find it, in context what I am doing is calculate the probability of a pair, two pairs etc to appear in a poker play using Montecarlo method, at the moment I'm using the `random.sample` function to do that, but I want to use my own methods to generate random numbers that return numbers between 0-1, and I want to use Discrete Uniform Distribution in order to be sure that every number has the same probability to appear.

I apreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Why not using `random.choice(range(1, 53))` directly? (instead of getting a random number in (0,1) and transforming it to a discrete number in [1, 52])

Comment: @LoMaPh the Mersenne Twister used by Python is good but not perfect; see [It is high time we let go of the Mersenne Twister](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06437).  I think it's fine to ask how to use alternatives.

Comment: Is the random number 0-1 floating point or is it a single bit integer?

Comment: Yes LoMaPh, but is pretty much the same I do with the random.sample function I'm using now, I mean this takes a sample of X size hand from the Poker list of 52 suits I generate.

Comment: @Mark Ransom the numbers my methods generate are pseudo random numbers, you know like 0.03245, 0.764... So I guess floating point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a math question more than python. here is the soln:

Code:

```
import random

arr_0_1 = [random.random() for i in range(10)]
print(arr_0_1)
d = 1/51
arr_1_52 = [n/d + 1  for n in arr_0_1]
print(arr_1_52)
```

Output:

```
[0.49864143060719257, 0.9124661869543931, 0.14064674065024652, 0.6162308610305717, 0.698038549502753, 0.18002207940954196, 0.7337352732415695, 0.34955525833304546, 0.6380173638897209, 0.14733996159513485]
[26.430712960966822, 47.535775534674045, 8.172983773162573, 32.42777391255916, 36.5999660246404, 10.18112604988664, 38.42049893532005, 18.82731817498532, 33.53888555837577, 8.514338041351877]
```

Comment: Yes, I think it can work in my program because I took the hands of poker of a size of 5 actually, but I find another way in a book, so I'm going to answer my own question, but your answer works too, also can't give you points, because I'm a new user, but I really appreaciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the number is a floating point number between 0 and 1 (range [0, 1)), you can do:

```
int(random() * 52)
```

to get a random `int` between 0 and 51 (range [0, 51]).
Or do:

```
int(random() * 52) + 1
```

to get a random `int` between 1 and 52 (range [1, 52]).

Comment: If the random range is `[0, 1]` instead of `[0, 1)` you can still use `int(random() * 52)` but check to see if the result is `52` and discard it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp4YN.png)

This solution is also valid, it gives me the same results.

Comment: Your image is simple text, so you should write it as text, rather than post an image of it.